# How to query db by uri id in laravel through user auth?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm just finished the intermediate laravel tutorial here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate and am trying to push on a bit.

While I can fetch all the tasks via auth'd user id with:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
    $tasks = $request->user()->tasks()->get();

    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks,
    ]);
    }
```

I want to create a view function... how, if I create a link to /task/7 to I query the info about the task with id 7 (for example) & send it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a route to match that `/task/7` URL like so:

```
Route::get("/task/{taskId}", "TaskController@getView");
```

Then, in your `TaskController`, define `getView` function as:

```
public function getView($taskId){
    $task = \App\Task::where("id", "=", $taskId)->first();

    return view("tasks.view")->with(["task" => $task]);
}
```

This is the simplest way to pass a `taskId` to via a URL parameter, query your DB for the matching record and return a view to display information about it.

There's more involved, like validating the record exists for example, but this should get you on your way.

Comment: Ace! Thanks. I never would have thought to call first();